# Attempting to count the number of tokens produced by strtok() in C

Tags: c, count, strtok

I am currently implementing a program where the user inputs push with a value or pop with a value. In order to split up the tokens I am using `strtok()`. All cases are working fine in my program except when the user inputs three values: For instance, the correct acceptable input would be "push 5" or "pop". When a user is to enter for instance: "push 5 7" I want to be able to count that there is 3 tokens and therefore reject the input. The program through the command line argument asks how many lines the user will input through `STDIN`, and hence I have a for loop. With my current counter it always returns the correct number of tokens the first loop but every loop after it returns 0.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int numlines = atoi(argv[1]);

    for(int i = 1; i<= numlines; i++){
       char str[256];
       fgets(str,256,stdin);

       str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = 0;

       char *tmp;
       char *token;
       char *tmp2;
       int count; //This is the counter for the tokens
       tmp = strtok(str," ");
       while(token != NULL){
          tmp2 = token;
          token = strtok(NULL, " ");
          count++;
   }
   printf("%d\n", count);
}
```

There is more code at the bottom that manipulates tmp and tmp2 tokens but that works fine. Again, the counter works for the first run through but always returns 0 after. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Maybe it's a typo, but it looks like you're missing the closing brace for the inner `while` loop.  There should be an additional closing brace after the `count++;` line.  Also, you don't initialize the `count` variable.

Comment: `int count;` lacks initialization.  Try `int count = 0;`

Comment: @bruceg yes that's just a typo from me writing on stack exchange, sorry about that.

Comment: Where is `token` getting initialized?

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline my tokens that I manipulate further in the program  are *tmp and *tmp2. The program is able to retrieves the tokens.

Comment: @chux I gave that a shot, outside the for loop, inside the for loop, and in the while loop and no cigar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`count` is declared inside the `for` loop, so it's not in scope after the loop ends. You need to declare it before the loop, and also initialize it to `0`.

Also, you should assign the result of the first `strtok()` to `token`. Otherwise, you're testing an uninitialized variable the first time through the loop.

I'm not sure what `tmp` and `tmp2` are for, since you never use them; I guess they're for code you haven't added yet, so I left them in.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int numlines = atoi(argv[1]);

    int count = 0; //This is the counter for the tokens

    for(int i = 1; i<= numlines; i++){
        char str[256];
        fgets(str,256,stdin);

        str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = 0;

        char *tmp;
        char *token;
        char *tmp2;
        tmp = token = strtok(str," ");
        while(token != NULL){
            tmp2 = token;
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            count++;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", count);
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for thank you kind sir @Barmar